# OutOfMemoryError on ViewPager + Navigation Drawer + GridView

Tags: java, android, memory-management, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I have a main `fragment` which creates 7 pages, `each pages` contain a `navigation drawer`, inside each navigation drawer contain a `gridview` which displays large images loaded from sd card handled by **universal-image-loader**. I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to handle a lot of pages.

`gPager.get().setOffscreenPageLimit(gABar.get().getTabCount());`

As I look into MAT (Memory Analyzing tool) and `Heap` tab inside `DDMS` the allocated memory keeps rising as well as the `heap` size, during my navigation (this is without orientation change). I tried putting `System.gc()` while navigation, it causes lag so I remove it. I already optimized my code by handling **(weak and soft) references**, **View Holder pattern** and **leaking `context`**. Even if I clicked `cause system gc` still the allotted memory is not lowered.

Would it be possible that the code below causes the **OOM**? I mean I instantiated the same fragment in four of my pages. `MainGroupFragment` - handles the drawer layout and also calling another fragment that handles the 'gridview display'. Is there any efficient way of instantiating such that it will not be causing OOM or saves the memory?

```
@Override public Parcelable saveState() { return null; }

@Override
public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
    Log.i("destroyItem", "MyFragmentPagerAdapter destroyItem");
    View view = (View)o;
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
    view = null;

}

 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        SavePref saveState = new SavePref(mContext.get());

        switch(arg0){
            /** Android tab is selected */
            case 0:
                //Bundle b = new Bundle();
                MainGroupFragment ItemID1 = new MainGroupFragment();
                ItemID1.variableAssigned("ItemID", mContext.get());
                ItemID1.saveSelecteditem("ItemID", 
                        ItemID1.selectedMainGroup.toString());
                //banquet.setRetainInstance(true);
                Log.i("#Inside MyFragmentPagerAdapter", "ItemID Value: " + 
                        ItemID1.selectedMainGroup.toString());
                //b.putCharSequence("mainGroup", "ItemID");
                //banquet.setArguments(b);
                return ItemID1;

            case 1:

                MainGroupFragment ItemID2 = new MainGroupFragment();
                ItemID2.variableAssigned("ItemID", mContext.get());
                saveState.saveSelecteditem("ItemID", 
                        ItemID2.selectedMainGroup.toString());
                //beverages.setRetainInstance(true);
                Log.i("#Inside MyFragmentPagerAdapter", "ItemID Value: " + 
                        ItemID2.selectedMainGroup.toString());

                return ItemID2;

            case 2:

                MainGroupFragment ItemID3 = new MainGroupFragment();
                ItemID3.variableAssigned("ItemID",  mContext.get());
                saveState.saveSelecteditem("ItemID", 
                        ItemID3.selectedMainGroup.toString());
                //food.setRetainInstance(true);
                Log.i("#Inside MyFragmentPagerAdapter", "ItemID Value: " + 
                        ItemID3.selectedMainGroup.toString());

                return ItemID3;

            case 3:

                MainGroupFragment ItemID4 = new MainGroupFragment();
                ItemID4.variableAssigned("OTHERS", mContext.get());
                saveState.saveSelecteditem("OTHERS", 
                        ItemID4.selectedMainGroup.toString());
                //others.setRetainInstance(true);
                Log.i("#Inside MyFragmentPagerAdapter", "OTHERS Value: " + 
                        ItemID4.selectedMainGroup.toString());

                return ItemID4;

            case 4: 
                HistoryFragment ItemID5 = new HistoryFragment();
                return ItemID5;

            case 5:
                OrdersFragment ItemID6 = new OrdersFragment();
                return ItemID6;

            case 6:
                FavoritesFragment ItemID7 = new FavoritesFragment();
                return ItemID7;


            default:
                //Bundle b2 = new Bundle();
                MainGroupFragment ItemID8 = new MainGroupFragment();
                ItemID8.variableAssigned("ItemID", mContext.get());
                saveState.saveSelecteditem("ItemID", 
                        ItemID8.selectedMainGroup.toString());

                return ItemID8;

        }

    }
```

**Only Suspect 1 according to MAT;**

```
One instance of "android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl" loaded by 

"dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4123f038" occupies 32,500,328 (70.23%) bytes. The memory is 

accumulated in one instance of "android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl" loaded by 

"dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4123f038".

Keywords
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x4123f038
```

---

What do you mean by this:

```
The FragmentManager seems to keep every Fragment forever. Make sure you destroy Fragments when you're done with them, simply detaching doesn't remove them from the manager.
```

**Update:**

Does this help?

```
  @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }
```